# Event listener for slash commands in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

### The Question

Is there something like an event listener for slash commands in `discord.py` or `discord-py-slash-command`, that execudes code when a slash command was send?

### What I know

As we all know, in discord.py there are event listeners, like `on_message`:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    await message.channel.send(f'You said {message.content}.')
```

And with `discord.ext` there a listeners for `commands`:

```
@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hi!')
```

And with `discord_slash` there are slash commands:

```
@slash.slash(
    name='hello',
    description='Say hello.'
)
async def _hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hi!')
```

### What I need

Regardless, I want to execute some code, whenever a slash command is used. I would imagine it to work like this:

```
@slash.event()
async def on_slash(ctx):
    # Something
```

Is there such a functionality in the mentioned libaries and if not, can I still somehow execude some code whenever a slash command was used?

*PS: First question, so I'm open to improvement suggestions.*

Comment: That sadly does not help, since I do not know if it is a command or a regular message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that you cannot listen to the slash command interactions of other bots, but if you want to set up a listener for your own slash commands you can use the  `on_interaction` listener:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_interaction(interaction):
    if str(interaction.type) == "InteractionType.application_command":
        print("test")
```

`application_command` is a slash command interaction, [here are the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=interaction#discord.InteractionType) for the other types.
And [here's the doc](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=interaction#discord.on_interaction) for `on_interaction` in general.

Also please keep in mind that this only got added in the discord.py 2.0 alpha version, so if you do not have the newest version installed already, you can install it with `pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py`.

Hope this is at least somewhat useful.